# Recursive Combination on Fortran

Tags: recursion, fortran, fortran90

I wrote a recursive program on Fortran to calculate the combinations of `npoints` of `ndim` dimensions as follows. I first wrote this program on MATLAB and it was perfectly running. But in Fortran, my problem is that after the first iteration it is assigning absurd values for the list of points, with no explanation. Could somebody give me a hand?

```
PROGRAM MAIN
   IMPLICIT NONE

   INTEGER :: ndim, k, npontos, contador,i,iterate, TEST
   integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: pontos

   print*, ' '
   print*, 'npoints?'
   read *, npontos
   print*, 'ndim?'
   read *, ndim
   k=1
   contador = 1
   open(450,file= 'combination.out',form='formatted',status='unknown')
   write(450,100) 'Comb  ','stat  ',(' pt ',i,' ',i=1,ndim)
   write(450,120) ('XXXXXXXXXX ',i=1,ndim+1)
   allocate(pontos(ndim)) 
   do i=1,4
   pontos(i)=i
   end do 

   TEST = iterate(pontos, ndim, npontos,k,contador)  



    end program MAIN



       recursive integer function iterate(pontos, ndim, npontos, k,contador)
           implicit NONE
           integer, intent(in) :: ndim, k, npontos
           integer,dimension(:) :: pontos
           integer contador,inic,i,j,m



           if (k.eq.ndim) then

                inic=pontos(ndim)

                do i = pontos(ndim),npontos
                    pontos(k)= i
                    write(*,*) pontos(:)


                    contador=contador+1

                end do

                pontos(ndim)= inic + 1                 
            else

                inic = pontos (k)

                do j = pontos(k),(npontos-ndim+k)

                    pontos(k)=j

                    pontos= iterate(pontos, ndim, npontos, k+1,contador)
                end do
            end if


            pontos(k)=inic+1;
           if (pontos(k).gt.(npontos-ndim+k+1)) then
                do m =k+1,ndim
                    pontos(m)=pontos(m-1)+1
                end do
            end if              


        end function iterate
```

Comment: Minor issue, probably not the cause of the error you report, but perhaps symptomatic of some lack of consideration of corner cases: what do you expect to happen when `ndim = 2`, say ?  Bearing in mind that your code will write to `pontos(4)` at some point.  I'd also like to see exactly how you build this code, as you've presented it it shouldn't compile.

Comment: Its just a test, the correct form would be pontos(ndim) in the do statment... I will try to pass a better form of the code

Answer (score 1):

There are too many issues in that code... I stopped debugging it. This is what I got so far, it's too much for a comment.

This doesn't make sense:

```
pontos= iterate(pontos, ndim, npontos, k+1,contador)
```

You are changing `pontos` inside `iterate`, and never set a return value within the function.

You need to a) provide a result statement for recursive functions (and actually set it) or b) convert it to a subroutine. Since you are modifying at least one dummy argument, you should go with b).

Since you are using assumed-shape dummy arguments, you need to specify an interface to the function/subroutine, either explicitly or with a module.

Neither format `100` nor format `120` are specified in your code.